# Enable ListView separators in unselectable Preferences

Tags: android

I want the Preferences ListView separators to be shown even on items that are not selectable.

Case 1:
Items are not selectable (what I need) and there are no separators (whan I don't need):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/storage_usage">

        <Preference
            android:key="pref_available_space"
            android:title="@string/available_space"
            android:selectable="false"
            android:shouldDisableView="false"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <Preference
            android:key="pref_used_by_library"
            android:title="@string/used_by_library"
            android:selectable="false"
            android:shouldDisableView="false"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <Preference
            android:key="pref_available_time"
            android:title="@string/available_time"
            android:selectable="false"
            android:shouldDisableView="false"
            android:enabled="false" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

In case you wonder why, the key is needed to set values from code. It does nothing but showing info.

[Screenshot](http://i45.tinypic.com/345g654.png)

Case 2:

If I set

```
selectable="true"
```

The items are selectable (what I don't need) and the separators are shown (what I need).

[Screenshot](http://i50.tinypic.com/xf8ec.png)

Comment: @Amokrane Chentir no, I accepted it as it was in that project - "disabled" ListView items without dividers.

Answer (score 0):

set tag for each preferences by `setTag()`. Then set the on click event. it will work fine

Comment: Then I should specify the selector or something, so it would not highlight when pressed.
I did not find setBackground method in a Preference.
If i disable the whole ListView than the upper stuff will be disabled also